# Calculate walking speed for people

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql-server to calculate human walking speed.  I have a table like:

```
Name   time(in min)  latitude longitude
Billy   1             x1       y1
Billy   2             x2       y2
...
Jim     1             k1       m1
Jim     2             k2       m2
...
Kate    1             l1       n1
Kate    2             l2       n2
```

I want to select the people whose average speed in some hour is between 5-7 m/hr. Here is my code to calculate the distance from point A to Point B using Haversin'law.

```
SELECT Name,
    3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((orig_lat1 - abs(dest_lat2)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)+ COS(orig_longitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest_lat2) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((orig_longitude - dest_longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
          AS distance
From Table1
Where distance>5 and distance<7
```

Where the orig_lat1,dest_lat2, etc are the latitude and longitude of original point and destination. However, I don't know how to track the speed dynamically, the table is updated every minute.

Thanks.

My thought is in the beginning to declare the latitude and longitude (both original and destination) in some certain way. Say:

```
DECLARE @orig_lat1 blabla
DECLARE @orig_long blabla
```

The Goal is to check the Average speed in at least an Hour. So if in any hour the people's speed is 5-7 mile/hour. Then print the people's name.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question here?  The formula to calculate speed?  "How do you track speed?" Why track Speed when you can calculate it.? Speed will constantly change, the best you can do is average speed which is distance / time= Rate.  Such as 5-7 miles per hour.  So our (distance / time) = Rate in Distance Units / Minute... Or are you asking how to do a self join to get the next "interval" and distance?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The equation here is just to calculate distance. In order to calculate the speed in mile/hr, I have to collect 1st-60th, 2nd-61st row for the latitude and longitude to calculate the speed. (because the table is updated every minutes).  How to achieve this goal please? That is the average speed I am looking for.

Comment: A visual example of the expected results would help here.  Do you want avg speed over all all entries for a name, speed between each entry?  too many unknowns still.  So if a person is out for a 2 hour walk do we show average speed over the entire 2 hours, or at each our, or between each interval?  say they go out for 1 walk now, and another walk later... How can we distinguish the separate walks so we don't mix lat/long measurements...  Start with the end in mind (a visual example will help with that)

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Please check my update in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question what you really need to do is join table 1 back to itself looking for the people who have traveled a distance that meets your criteria.

I'm going to make an assumption you are looking for people who have traveled at this speed for a certain amount of time.  I decided to make it a variable so you could play around with the amount of time you wanted to sample for.

```
 declare @duration int

set @duration = 1

   SELECT a.Name
          ,a.lat
          ,a.long
          ,b.lat
          ,b.long
          ,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((a.lat - abs(b.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)
             + COS(a.long * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(b.long) * pi()/180) 
             * POWER(SIN((a.long - b.long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
          AS distance
From Table1  a
inner join Table1 b
  on a.personID = b.personID
  and a.time = b.time +  @duration
Where 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((a.lat - abs(b.lat)) 
      * pi()/180 / 2), 2)+ COS(a.long * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(b.long) 
      * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((a.long - b.long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
       between 5 and 7
```

Comment: Doesn't that assume people never change direction over @duration? Granted, the best one can do with the data is assume no one changes direction within a single minute, making that assumption over the entire hour doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks phipywr, this duration method is what I need , but Dwal mention a exception that I have never thought of. Yes, what if the people go back and forth, it is very tricky.

Comment: If they go back and forth they aren't really traveling 5-7 miles per hour based upon the criteria provided above.  They are traveling unspecified distances, but given the way the data is collected all you can really do is compare the distances apart.  That is the reason why I dialed it back to just look at it from minute to minute, because what if the person stops and talks for a little while.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wait until the 61st minute's entry has been added. Then use:

```
SELECT NAME FROM
(SELECT Name,
  3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((orig_lat1 - abs(dest_lat2)) * pi()/180 / 2),   2)+ COS(orig_longitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest_lat2) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((orig_longitude - dest_longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
AS distance
From Table1 Where time=1) F
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Name,
  3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((orig_lat1 - abs(dest_lat2)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)+ COS(orig_longitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest_lat2) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((orig_longitude - dest_longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
AS distance
From Table1 where time=61) S
ON F.Name=S.Name 
WHERE (F.Distance + S.Distance) BETWEEN 5 AND 7
```

This assumes that the names are all unique and that the times in the table are recorded in minutes, but you want the final units to be hours.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Your method is easy to understand. But if when time goes forward, how to check speed from 2nd minutes to 62 minutes? And more time window please ? should I define some variable to increase time please?

Comment: Take off the Where Time = x.  In the Select, include ,time.  Then in the ON clause of the join, put AND F.Time+60=S.Time